# Modify html2text library

Tags: php, html

I have been using [Html2Text library by Jon Abernathy](http://www.chuggnutt.com/html2text) for a while but now I have a new requirement. Usually the library formats the output text according to the input html like: `<b>i am bold</b>` will become "HELLO I AM BOLD".

**Requirement**: What I need to do right now is have the library not convert if it finds something like: `${this should be not touched}$` including the $ sign and braces.

**Question**: Is there a better way (perhaps passing parameters) in achieving the above behavior instead of directly modifying the library code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify the HTML or the library. Just add this to your stylesheet:

```
b { text-transform:uppercase; }
```

Now the content of your `<b>` tags will be displayed in upper case as well as bold.

If you have specific `<b>` tags that need to be upper-cased and others that don't, then use a `class` to differentiate them, and change the above CSS to reference the class name.